# How to authenticate AAD token from PPE environment using OWIN?

Tags: owin

I am using below code to authenticate AAD access token.

```
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigSettings.MicrosoftAadTenant,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                }
            });
```

The code works fine until I switched to use a token generated from PPE environment, whose Iss is "https://sts.windows-ppe.net/...". I pasted error message below. Do you know how to fix it?

> Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware
>   Error: 0 : Authentication failed
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException:
>   IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve
>   SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
>       (
>       IsReadOnly = False,
>       Count = 2,
>       Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0x871BE0E2BDD307841D01C8151AE2717D2DB9F376),
>       Clause[1] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
>       ) ',

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I find out why. Looking at Microsoft Owin source code at [git repo](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/9f6e09af6bf203744feb5347121fe25f6eec06d8/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationExtensions.cs), the login url is hard coded. There is no way to config it. I fix the issue by writing my own extension method.